# Get N Number of subwebs for specified web

Tags: spweb, spwebcollection

How to get All Subwebs upto N Levels for Specified Web.

eg.

My Site url is...

"http://server/web1"

I need all subwebs upto N Levels for web1..

below line get all subwebs upto N Levels of sitecollection

```
SPWebCollection allwebcoll = spsite.AllWebs;
```

but i dont need all subwebs upto N Levels of site collection.

I need all subwebs upto N Levels for **specified web**.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to recursive for specific `SPWeb` than

try this :

```
   SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
   recursive(web);
```

function for recursive :

```
 protected void recursive(SPWeb web)
    {
        string webTitle = web.Title;

        if (web.Webs.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (SPWeb oweb in web.Webs)
            {
                recursive(oweb);
            }
        }

       if(web != null)
          web.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: yes this way gud... but i looking for direct property or methods available...
So we reduce and iterate loops for getting subwebs..

Comment: as par my knowledge : only one direct method available like `SPWebCollection webcoll= SPWeb.Webs` for this requirement

Comment: remember to dispose!
Several examples of what you want to achieve on this site like [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45925/dispose-spweb-object-in-recursive-function) and yes you need to recursively call .Webs and set a "depth" counter for each recursion until N has been reached

Comment: ohh yes!! i forget to mention it.i have updated my answer. thanks